# How to specify changes complement in gitlab ci?

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci

`gitlab` has introduces [rules](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/#rules) and changes that allow specifying jobs to run when changes occur.
I wonder how can I configure the job to be skipped or ignore a path?

For example, I want to run the ci for any change unless it is a change in the `docs` path.
If a change occured both in the `src` and `docs` then the job should be executed,
but if the change was only in the `docs` folder, then the job should not be executed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Update 2**
GitLab uses globs for their `rules: changes`. There is no direct way of excluding folders in standard globs, but we can work around it and include everything except files in the folder `docs`:

```
myjob:
  script: build myproject
  rules:
   - changes:
     - "*"
     - "?/**/*"
     - "??/**/*"
     - "???/**/*"
     - "[^d]???/**/*"
     - "?[^o]??/**/*"
     - "??[^c]?/**/*"
     - "???[^s]/**/*"
     - "?????*/**/*"
     when: on_success
```

The first `*` matches all files. The second to forth glob lines matches everything in folders that have 1-3 characters. The fifth line matches everything inside of folders that are four characters long, except if it starts with a `d`. The line after this matches all folders that are four characters long, except if the second char is a `o`. The two next lines does the same for `c` and `s`, and together these four lines matches all folders that have four characters, except `docs`.

The last line matches everything inside of folders that are five or more characters long.

**Update**
When I understood the question properly:

```
myjob:
  script: build myproject
  rules:
   - changes:
     - docs/**/*
     when: never
   - when: on_success
```

This job is skipped if there are changes to `docs`, and otherwise it behaves as a normal job and is run if all jobs from the previous stage has succeeded.

**Old answer**
Something like this should work:

```
myjob:
  script: build myproject
  rules:
   - changes:
     - src/**/*
     when: on_success
   - changes:
     - docs/**/*
     when: never
```

The rules are evaluated from top to bottom. If there are changes to any file in the `src` directory, the job will get the attribute `when: on_success`. This is the default for GitLab jobs, and means that this job will be executed if all jobs of the previous stage has been executed.

If the first rule doesn't match, the second job will be evaluated. If there are any changes to the `docs` folder, the job will get the attribute `when: never`, and the job will never execute.

The second rule could be changed to:

```
- when: never
```

But I imagine that your real task is a bit more complicated that your question, and that you might need this whole rule.

Comment: it's actually not more complicated.. but the solution is not good enough since I want to execute the job on any change **but** the `docs`. I don't know how every service is built, and not all of the code is under the `src` folder. Someone may want to execute the job if `tests`, `__tests__`, `dockerfile` etc has changed

Comment: the updated answer is pretty good, but it could be a problem if both the `docs` changed and the source code changed, in which case I would like to execute the job

Comment: I'm not sure if it is possible to achieve what you want. Both the  `rules` and `only/except` in GitLab CI uses glob patterns for matching files. The standard glob patterns doesn't have a way for excluding paths, but in some places it works to write `!(docs/**/*)` to mean "everything that doesn't match `docs/**/*`. GitLab excepts globs like that for the changes, but it doesn't seem to match anything.

Comment: I added a way of writing the `rules: changes` so that if only `docs` are changed, the job is skipped, but if anything else is also changed, then the job is executed.